# Is "a person without desire" correct?

Tags: articles

Can I use desire in its singular form without an article before it? That is, if I write "...so also a person without desire", will that be correct? or I'll have to use "..so also a person without any desire" or "..without desires"?

Comment: Consider "a person who **desires** nothing"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use it without an article.

Thinking of other examples:

> I'm without coffee.
>   I'm without money.

It seems that leaving out the article makes *desire* act as an mass noun, which works great with *desire*, but would be a problem for nouns that cannot act as such. So you can **not** say:

> A person without apple.

Since [desire](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/desire) can be used as a mass noun or not, you are free to add the article or leave it out.

Comment: Yeah, I am just not sure about whether desire, which has plural form desires, can be used as an uncountable noun, like coffee and money.

Comment: Yes it can, and since I don't want you to take my word for it, I added a [reference](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/desire) to my answer as well (meaning 1.1)

Answer (score 0):

It should be a person **[without desire](http://suicideproject.org/2013/06/a-person-without-desire-is-a-person-without-hope/)** (or *with no desire*) if you're referring to a person constantly desireless or on the ragged edge of depression.